# My application is deployed to n number of servers. I need to find number of servers where my application is installed for one org wise dashboard.

Tags: java, sockets

My application is deployed to n number of servers. I need to find number of servers where my application is installed for one org wise dashboard.

I could only figure out that sockets can be used to get the IP of all the servers..

Comment: Does your application listen on a particular port? Is it a web application of some?

Comment: Are the servers on the same local network?

Comment: yes..servers are on the same network..

Comment: yes..we have a fixed port to listen..and this is a web application.